# Putting a wav file into an ArrayList consisiting of collections of frames

Tags: java, arraylist, buffer, wav

I have used code from to create a buffer from a wav file in which data is read in blocks of 100 frames.

Please see link below for original code:

http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html

I now need to create an ArrayList in which each element consists of 100 frames from the wav file (The first element 0-99, the second 100-199 etc...)

I am having trouble figuring out how to implement this into the code I've currently tried:

```
     // Display information about the wav file
     wavFile.display();

     // Get the number of audio channels in the wav file
     int numChannels = wavFile.getNumChannels();

     // Create a buffer of 100 frames
     double[] buffer = new double[100 * numChannels];

     int framesRead;


     do
     {
        // Read frames into buffer
        framesRead = wavFile.readFrames(buffer, 100);

      }
     while (framesRead != 0);

     // Close the wavFile
     wavFile.close();
```

I am not sure what way in which I should construct the Array List, or populate it.

Any advice about how I can achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can make a class that stores an array of the 100 frames as a class variable then declare an ArrayList<YourClass> and then just declare a new Object of the 100 frames each time and push it to the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

I made a class for the frames assuming they are stored as an `int` array(can easily be modified for `double` or any other type you want stored).  The idea of this code is to create a container class of `Frames` that will be used to create the `ArrayList`, which will make it easy to access your arrays of 100 stored values later.

```
public class Frames {

private int[] frames;

public Frames() {
}

public Frames(int[] frames)
{
    this.frames = frames;
}

public int[] getFrames() {
    return frames;
}

public void setFrames(int[] frames) {
    this.frames = frames;
 }

}
```

This would be used in your method like this as an example:

```
    ArrayList<Frames> list = new ArrayList<Frames>();
    //This would be your 100 values stored as an array
    int[] arr = {123,234,2342,1234124,12341}; 
    Frames frames = new Frames(arr);

    //Add the frames to the list(you will be doing this in a loop to continue adding them)
    list.add(frames);
```

It will just need to be modified to add the values you are getting from your loop.  Every time you get your array of 100 values, you declare `new Frames(yourValues)` and then just add that to the `ArrayList`